# C++ is there anyway I can set a life cycle for recv function in WinSock?

Tags: c++, sockets, http, server, recv

Here is the code I have for accept and recv
int sock = createSocket();
int rc = ::bind(sock, glDispenserServerConfig->m_szServerPort);

```
sockaddr_in clientAddr;
int clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
int clientSock;
bool saveImage;
while (-1 != (clientSock = accept(sock,(sockaddr*)&clientAddr, (socklen_t*)&clientAddrSize))) {
        string requestStr;
        int bufSize = 5;
        requestStr.resize(bufSize); 
      
        string data = "";
        string::size_type position;
        bool getFlag = false;
        while(1) {
            recv(clientSock, &requestStr[0], bufSize, 0);
            data += requestStr;
            // position = data.find("}");
            if(requestStr[0] == '}') 
                break;
            else if(requestStr[1] == '}')
                break;
            else if(requestStr[2] == '}')
                break;
            else if(requestStr[3] == '}')
                break;
            else if(requestStr[4] == '}')
                break;
            if(requestStr[0] == 'G' && requestStr[1] == 'E' && requestStr[2] == 'T' && requestStr[3] == ' ') {
                getFlag = true;
                for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    recv(clientSock, &requestStr[0], bufSize, 0);
                    data += requestStr;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

And two function being used:

```
int createSocket() {
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (sock == -1) {
            printf("Create socket failed!\n");
        }
        return sock;
    }


bool bind(int &sock, unsigned short port) {
    if (sock <= 0) {
        createSocket();
    }

    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port); 
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(0); 

    if (::bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {    
        printf("bind port %d failed!\n", port);
        return false;
    }
    printf("bind port %d succeeded.\n", port);
    listen(sock, 10);
    return true;
}
```

I was trying to get data stream from POST request. Since the size of body is unknown, I made a loop to read the whole body. And this port is designed for getting POST request, so I break the loop and made a flag for later use.
My issue here is I check the ending symbol which is "}" here. I'm worried about sometime if missing the ending symbol the server will be blocked by recv function.
So I wonder if there is some way I can set recv max waiting time, like 2 seconds it did not read anything from buffer then break the loop and continuous?

Comment: You can't assume that  `requestStr` receives five characters. You must check the return value of `recv`.

Comment: somehow the server I am using if I set requestStr size larger than 5, then the data I get will have lots error, so I use loop to read all the buffer until get the ending symbol "}". I have no problem about receive data correctly now, just want to add some error recovery. The server was designed for receiving base64 image(should be about 4MB each) string and decode it and save to another server.

Comment: What you receive is an unstructured stream of octets, and you can't assume anything at all about what you `recv`. If it appears to work right now, it's just a coincidence. Get yourself an introduction to networking.

Comment: I see, I will try to fix that. And I still want to know is there anyway I can make recv end if it waited more than 2 second, the only solution I found so far was to make a thread call shutdown which I'm not really feel comfortable to use that.

Comment: Look up the `select` function.

Comment: A timeout for `recv()` can be handled using `select()` or `setsockopt(SO_RCVTIMEO)`. However, this code is simply setup all wrong. A `POST` implies HTTP is used. You have to parse the data being received to determine where each request ends. Only then can you process data correctly. Read RFCs 2616 and 7230..7235, which define the HTTP 1.1 protocol. In particular, pay attention to RFC 2616 Section 4.4 and RFC 7230 Section 3.3.3, which define the size of each HTTP message. I've posted [pseudo code](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A65863+http+pseudo) on this matter many times before.

Comment: I will take closer look to select(), I tried yesterday but did not get what I expected. To molbdnilo my recv somehow just works fine, I try to chance length by 1 many times it works fine. To Remy Lebeau thank you for helping me to make it more standard but this port for me is pure POST request receiver, I wasn't even plan to set other response other than 200 and 404

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments from [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863), here is my new code:

```
sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    int32 clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
    int32 clientSock;
    bool saveImage;
    struct timeval timeout;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(timeout);
    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    while (-1 != (clientSock = accept(sock, (sockaddr*)&clientAddr, (socklen_t*)&clientAddrSize))) {
        int err = setsockopt(clientSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout.tv_sec, sizeof(struct timeval));
```

This will stop blocking by recv in 10 seconds